# Custom ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview

I want to create a custom list view in app...
but I don't understand why my code have problem to run it
when I run my app ...Shows Message as "app is stopped" ..
I'm confused..
Help me to solve this
thank you
java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    Myadapter adapter=new Myadapter(getApplicationContext());
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

public class Myadapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    LayoutInflater myInflater;
    public Myadapter(Context context) {
        myInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (4);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return  position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder Holder;

        if(convertView==null)
        {
            Holder=new ViewHolder();
            convertView=myInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null);
            Holder.star=(ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton_star);
            Holder.vorod=(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_voro);
            Holder.url=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_addres);
            Holder.vorod=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton_star);
            Holder.rank=(ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton_rank);
            Holder.speed=(ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_speed);
            Holder.delete=(ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton_delete);
            convertView.setTag(Holder);



        }
        else
            Holder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();



        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return convertView;
    }



}

public class ViewHolder
{
    ImageButton star;
    Button vorod;
    TextView url;
    ImageButton rank;
    ImageButton speed;
    ImageButton detail;
    ImageButton delete;

}

}
```

Xml code:(Item list view)

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="30dp"
android:background="@drawable/image001"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/imageButton_star"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
     android:background="@drawable/round"
     android:src="@drawable/star1"
 />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_voro"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/text_addres"
    android:background="@drawable/corner_round"
    android:text="button" />
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_addres"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="9dp"

    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/olgo"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageView_speed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/round"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/speed" />



    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_dataile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/round"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/dataile" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_rank"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/round"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:src="@drawable/ranke" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/round"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/delete" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and main Xml: There is a listView

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: YES PLEASE post the log cat where it dies. probably a null pointer exception

Comment: also post your main xml layout as well as the item view

Answer (score 0):

you have this in code:

```
Holder.star=(ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton_star);
```

but you have not a `Button` with id `imageButton_star` in your xml file.

You are inilizating `Holder.vorod` twice 
**Remove**

```
Holder.vorod=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton_star);
```

Comment: @behroooz I don't see it in your above xml file. it is ImageButton.

Comment: @behroooz You have `ImageButton` with id `imageButton_star`, avoid blind copy paste.

Comment: @VenomVendor It's correct, but if behroooz post our log maybe provide  better help. Maybe problem is another thing